# What is the value of "this" for an object created with constructor in 'javascript' using new keyword

Tags: javascript, this

Here is javascript function :

`case(1)` --(1)

```
function Friend(area, favLan){
  this.area = area;
  this.favLan = favLan;
  this.context = this;
  return(this);
}

alert(new Friend("cl", "js") === "<what????>");
```

//what should be written at the place of "" so that alert gives output "true".

Like in the case given below:- `case(2)` --(2)

```
function Friend(area, favLan){
  this.area = area;
  this.favLan = favLan;
  this.context = this;
  return(this);
}

alert(Friend("cl", "js") === "<what????>");
```

The value to be written at the place of "" should be "window"(removing quotation marks) so that the output is `true`.

I understand that in `second` case the this will owned by the window object as it in the global context but in the first `case` this will be owned by the object created with `new` keyword but what is the value of the `this` here??

It would be really appreciated if one can explain, why the output of following javascript is `"The Window"`???

```
var name = "The Window";
　　var object = {
　　　　name : "My Object",
　　　　getNameFunc : function(){
　　　　　　return function(){
　　　　　　　　return this.name;
　　　　　　};
　　　　}
　　};
　　alert(object.getNameFunc()()); // outputs <The Window>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: A couple of articles for you to read: [Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) and [Inheritance and the Prototype Chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

Comment: Perhaps you mean `alert(Friend("cl", "js").favLan === "js");` since you cannot compare the object to another object. You can create a comparison function in the object to return the equalities of the strings inside it